# Why isn't touch listener removed when Sprite is removed?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have the following code for checking for touches on a sprite:

```
void SpriteBlock::addEvents()
{
auto listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

listener->onTouchBegan = [&](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    Vec2 p = touch->getLocation();
    Rect rect = this->getBoundingBox();

    if(rect.containsPoint(p))
    {
        return true; // to indicate that we have consumed it.
    }

    return false; // we did not consume this event, pass thru.
};

listener->onTouchEnded = [=](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    SpriteBlock::touchEvent(touch);
};

cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(listener, 30);
}


void SpriteBlock::touchEvent(cocos2d::Touch* touch)
{
}
```

This seems to work fine, but even after the sprite is destroyed, it still gets triggered (if I click on the last place the sprite existed), and It crashes with:

"

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7....)

"

at the following line:

```
    Rect rect = this->getBoundingBox();
```

Now it seems clear to me that the sprite is destroyed because my destructor is set to display a log message when it is triggered (which it does):

```
SpriteBlock::~SpriteBlock() {
    CCLOG("Block destroyed"); 
}
```

So what is the problem here ? Why isn't the listener destroyed with my sprite ? I destroy my sprite by doing the following:

```
    mysprite->removeFromParent();
```

When I create the sprite, I do not store any references. I just add it to the main layer of my scene, so it shouldn't remain. I create it using:

```
SpriteBlock *block = SpriteBlock::create();
```

How do I make sure the touch listener is also removed when the sprite is removed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto listener = cocos2d::EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
```

store it as a variable in SpriteBlock class.

Then in SpriteBlock destructor remove a listener.

Comment: Right - its mentioned on a different page on the cocos2d site, but wasn't apparent from the article explaining how to use the listener. Apparently some kinds of listeners are removed automatically, but types like this need to be explicitly removed.

Comment: @Makalele can you describe more on how to remove listener in destructor?

Comment: cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->removeEventListener(listener);